# Which method on HttpURLConnection makes request to the given URL

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have below code to make a HTTP call using standalone Java program, can someone please let me know which line/method actually makes HTTP call to the URL.

As per below code I understand that I am getting a connection object and providing the request method type as "GET" and also giving authorization details to it.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("<Some URL String>").openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

BASE64Encoder enc = new BASE64Encoder();
StringBuffer userpassword = new StringBuffer().append(username).append(":").append(password);
String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode(userpassword.toString().getBytes());
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);

BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
// Read the response
String line;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = serverResponse.readLine()) != null) {
response.append(line);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BufferedReader serverResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

This method is responsible to make HTTP request.
It is obvious that we are getting response on this line of code and we are calling InputStreamReader from where it is getting Response back.

Comment: Hi Nivesh, Thanks a lot for the response. So just calling the method connection.getInputStream() is making HTTP call internally?

Comment: yes you can try to debug this by calling this method and on server you can see when this line of code executes the request reaches there(on server)

Answer (score 0):

It the line

```
connection.getInputStream()
```

Answer (score 0):

[`connection.getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream%28%29) returns an input stream that reads from this open `connection`.

Answer (score -1):

You could call [`.connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) to actually "Open[s] a communications link".

Comment: Hi, without calling .connect() method I am able to getting response from URL.